# Nominatim Updater Service: it updates strictly Nominatim DB or also data in PostGIS DB?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, nominatim

I was wondering whether Nominatim Updater service is doing changes to Nominatim DB only?
Or it also updates record in PostGIS DB?
Cheers,
Ivo